# Unable to Login using datas from SQLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi I am trying to login into my application using the data I already stored in my SQLite database (where I successfully registered). I have been struggling with coding my Login page right. All I want is to be able to Login with matching data from my database.

It would be great if someone could help me with snippets of coding as I'm a beginner in these android development area. Also I am not a very smart programming student. Thank you!

This is my Login class:

```java
 public class Login extends Activity{
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    Button btnLogin;
    EditText NRIC,Password;
    Editable d1,d2 = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }

    //Event handler from Login page to Homepage
        public void buttonOnClick (View v) {
            btnLogin = (Button)  findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
            btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    d1 = NRIC.getText();
                    d2 = Password.getText();
                    try{

                        Cursor c = db.getRecord("SELECT * FROM assignments", null);
                        if(c!= null){
                            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                                do {
                                    //whole data of column is fetched by getColumnIndex()
                                    String nric =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("custNRIC"));
                                    String password =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("custPassword"));
                                    System.out.println(nric);
                                    System.out.println(password);
                                }while(c.moveToNext());}
                            //count the total number of entries
                            Integer a =  c.getCount();
                            System.out.println(a);
                            //db1.close();
                            //if you close the database then illegal exception will be occurred...
                        }} catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Homepage.class));
                    }
                }
            });

            }
       }
```

And here's my DBAdapter:

```java
    public class DBAdapter {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "custId";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "custName";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "custPhone";
    public static final String KEY_GENDER = "custGender";
    public static final String KEY_DOB = "custDOB";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "custAddress";
    public static final String KEY_NRIC = "custNRIC";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "custEmail";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "custPassword";
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "powerfood";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "assignments";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
            "create table if not exists assignments (id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + "custName VARCHAR not null, custPhone VARCHAR, custGender VARCHAR, custDOB VARCHAR, custAddress VARCHAR, custNRIC VARCHAR, custEmail VARCHAR, custPassword VARCHAR );";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS customer");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a record into the database---
    public long insertRecord(String custName, String custPhone, String custGender, String custDOB, String custAddress, String custNRIC, String custEmail, String custPassword)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, custName);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, custPhone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_GENDER, custGender);
        initialValues.put(KEY_DOB, custDOB);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, custAddress);
        initialValues.put(KEY_NRIC, custNRIC);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, custEmail);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, custPassword);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }
//---retrieves a particular record---
    public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NRIC, KEY_PASSWORD},
                        KEY_NRIC + "=?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId)}, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
```

This is what my Logcat shows.

```java
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
C:\Users\L33545\Downloads\Powerfood2014\app\src\main\java\com\powerfood2014\app\Login.java
error: method getRecord in class DBAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: long
found: String,<null>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: are you getting data from database or not, can you please tell me.

Comment: nope it doesn't trace from my database.

Comment: you have to debug it, i think kysha, or u have to send your code to me to check

Comment: so could you pass me your email?

Comment: hey, have you got my mail or not?

Comment: no I didn't get any mail from you but anyway my problem is solved. thank you so much!

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. I will get to you whenever I need help from you. Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

you are passing string in getRecord method

```
 Cursor c = db.getRecord("SELECT * FROM assignments", null);
```

where as you define in method definition that it will take long .

```
 public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException{
 ....
```

replace your onClick with this

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                d1 = NRIC.getText().toString();
                d2 = Password.getText().toString();
                try{

                    Cursor c = db.getRecord(Long.valueOf(d1));
                    if(c!= null){
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                            do {
                                //whole data of column is fetched by getColumnIndex()
                                String nric =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("custNRIC"));
                                String password =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("custPassword"));
                                System.out.println(nric);
                                System.out.println(password);
                            }while(c.moveToNext());}
                        //count the total number of entries
                        Integer a =  c.getCount();
                        System.out.println(a);
                        //db1.close();
                        //if you close the database then illegal exception will be occurred...
                    }} catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Homepage.class));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: sorry I'm just a student. It would be helpful if you could show me some codes to make changes.

Comment: let me try to change it..wait.

Comment: It would help if you show snippets of the correct codes. Or maybe a link where I can get help from. Thanks Waqar!

Comment: sorry. i wasnt able to update my answer. stackoverflow was get down.

Comment: Sorry it still doesnt work for me. :/ is there a tutorial where there's clear instructions to follow?

Comment: for tutorials ..follow these links...http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html ... http://hmkcode.com/android-simple-sqlite-database-tutorial/ ... http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm ... http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial

Comment: if you don't mind helping me out you can drop your email and i'll send you my zip file from there. thank you for still trying to help me out! and thanks for the links too!